# Constrain events to a certain duration in Full calendar io (javascript plugin)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

is there a way to constrain events to certain duration in the Full Calendar io javascript plugin? For example, I want all events in the calendar to be exactly 40 minutes.

Thanks a lot.